# CREATING TABLE USING DATA FRAME in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddData, schema).show(false)
```

When I try to register as table I'm getting below error

```
df.registerTempTable("bankDetails")
42:error registerTempTable is not a member of unit
```

Comment: you call `show` at the end of first line. `show` returns `Unit`, not a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `show(false)` method and should work, `show()` has `return` type as `Unit`.

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddData, schema)

df.registerTempTable("bankDetails")
```